# Vim in ex-command mode, how to complete the path only up to the first non unique match?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, filepath

I'm in a directory with many subfolders with a common prefix:

```
./pref-apple
./pref-aubergine
./pref-mango
./pref-milk
```

I have a file in one of these folder and I want vim to auto-complete the path just up to the first non-ambiguous match

`:e ./p<TAB>` -> `:e ./pref-`

`:e ./pref-au<TAB>` -> `:e ./pref-aubergine/`

while at the moment it will auto-complete with the full first folder-name. `:e ./p<TAB>` -> `:e/pref-apple/`

How can I do that?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/40378/how-to-make-vims-auto-complete-behave-like-bashs-default-auto-complete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to `set wildmode=longest`.

More info at [`:help 'wildmode'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'wildmode')

Comment: I use `set wildmode=longest:full,list:full`. I find it to be a nice balance of completing and listing out alternate completions.